# python sqlite only compares first 16-ish characters of string and ignores rest when searching table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite table in Python:

```
CREATE TABLE lookup (  id string PRIMARY KEY  );
```

In this table I inserted a lot of rows and then I created an index:

```
CREATE INDEX intindex ON lookup(id);
```

I now want to test if my string is in the table. I tried the following:

```
checkval = cursor.execute("""SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM lookup
                              WHERE id=?
                              LIMIT 1)""", (str(mystring), )).fetchone()[0]
```

But the problem is, this only seems to check if the first 16 or so characters of the string are identical.
For example, I know that my table contains:

```
'95592037576585500895905906368332492139177507248814568869956683982249018785792'
```

However, if I check the non-existing value:

```
'95592037576585501898360696547541541617886282712262516411315613154848368326494'
```

then I also get `TRUE`.

Checking:

```
'95592137576585500895905906368332492139177507248814568869956683982249018785792'
```

does correctly result in `FALSE`.

Why is it not comparing the full string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite there is no data type `STRING`.
If you use it as the data type of a column then as it is explained in [Determination Of Column Affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity), the column will have `NUMERIC` affinity.
So, values like:

```
'95592037576585500895905906368332492139177507248814568869956683982249018785792'
```

and

```
'95592037576585501898360696547541541617886282712262516411315613154848368326494'
```

will be considered as floating point numbers and because of precision limits, their value will be:

```
9.5592037576586E+76
```

so actually they are equal.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c5ce7da5588d9f44a7eea8bd7df01d98).

For strings there is only the `TEXT` data type in SQLite and you should change the column's definition to that.

Also you should not use `LIMIT` in your code.
`EXISTS` does not perform a full scan in the query because it returns as soon as it finds the first row matching the condition.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your id is of type *string* instead *text*: [""STRING" has an affinity of NUMERIC, not TEXT."](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  When I insert those large values sqlite3 seems to store them as floating points instead of text.  Floating points have limited number of digits it can store accurately.

```
CREATE TABLE lookup ( id text PRIMARY KEY not null );
```

Also you may get an implicit index on the primary key.